# Is it possible to call external R script from R markdown (.Rmd) in RStudio?

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

It's fairly trivial to load external R scripts as per [this R Sweave example](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/):

```
<<external-code, cache=FALSE>>=
read_chunk('foo-bar.R')
@
```

Can the same be done for R Markdown?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel AFAIK, this specific question has not been answered before, and since I know the answer, [I am encouraged to self-answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions).

Comment: Once, maybe. Twice, gets suspicious.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Why suspicious? SO is a Q&A site where answering your own question is encouraged. If someone has a question, searches SO and cannot find an answer, but does find the answer with their own research then we should be happy that they return here to provide that answer for others with the same question later.

Comment: @DanMidwood, it is suspicious behaviour because in both cases it has been just parroting back either the help file directly, or the examples from the  website which acts as the help.

Answer (score 16):

Yes.

Put this at the top of your R Markdown file:

````r
```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, cache=FALSE)
read_chunk('../src/your_code.R')
```
````

Delimit your code with the following hints for `knitr` (just like @yihui does in the [example](https://bitbucket.org/stat/knitr/downloads/Stat579-HW8-Xie.R)):

```r
## @knitr part1
plot(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))

## @knitr part2
plot(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))
```

In your R Markdown file, you can now have the snippets evaluated in-line:

````
Title
=====

Foo bar baz...

```{r part1}
```

More foo...

```{r part2}
```
````

Comment: Sorry, @opyate, do you know, is it possible to use multi-words hints (like `# @knitr part one`)? After some testing I assume that's not possible but may be I'm just missing something...

Comment: I'm not currently set up to test this suggestion, but try putting them on two separate lines?

Comment: What do you mean? It's no problem to put another word on another line. But knitr only recognizes one word as it seems to me... (The point is I already have comments in my file that divide that file into sections. And in order not to multiply entities I was thinking to re-use those existing comments also with knitr... But unfortunately that doesn't seem to work :)).

Comment: Let me clarify: ```# @knitr part``` then on the next line ```# @knitr one```.

Comment: Just for clarity: nope, that dosen't work, too. Anyway, thanks for your support.

Comment: How about escaping the space? e.g. ```# @knitr one\ two```

Comment: Nope, sorry :). (Tried different quotation marks, too… With the same result.)

Comment: The worst part is that it seems you to can't actually add anything after the first word after `# @knitr`. I.e., I use RStudio's folding by adding `####` at the end of comment to separate different sections – and no, you can't do that. As a result, have to duplicate quite a lot of comments.

Comment: And the only solution to avoid that seems to read file first, play with `sub` in some way, produce tmp file for the knitting only, `read_chunk` that tmp file, knit, delete tmp file.