# How to include external R file with RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Let's say I have (1) a Markdown file with some text and R code (code should not be evaluated, just printed out) and I have (2) an R file with some user-defined functions, which, again, should not be evaluated but only printed out.

Now, I want to combine those two as an RMarkdown article (to place those user-defined function (2) in some kind of Appendix). I know how to include Markdown files (`child='FILENAME.md'`), but how to include an external R file with syntax highlighting?

Yes, I know, I can just copy the contents of that R file (2) to my main Markdown file (1), add some `{r}`, and everything will be fine. Except that I still want to keep those two separate...

Is it possible?

Comment: Good question. I want to know too.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeWise, I was afraid I failed to express the problem clear  enough :) (English is not my native language).

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796501/is-it-possible-to-call-external-r-script-from-r-markdown-rmd-in-rstudio) could be relevant

Comment: Thanks, @zx8754, that indeed helped.

Comment: Did it work, if yes mark it as duplicate?