# Externalise config file and functions in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

I am having problems understanding the (practical) difference between the different ways to externalise code in R notebooks. Having referred to previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796501/is-it-possible-to-call-external-r-script-from-r-markdown-rmd-in-rstudio) or to the [documentation](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/), it is still unclear the difference in sourcing external `.R` files or `read_chunk()` them. For practical purposes let us consider the below:

1. I want to load libraries with an external `config.R` file: the most intuitive way, according to me, seems to create `config.R` as

   ```
   library(first_package)
   library(second_package)
   ...
   ```

   and, in the general R notebook (say, `main.Rmd`) call it like

   ````
   ```{r}
   source('config.R')
   ```

   ```{r}
   # use the libraries included above
   ```
   ````

   However, this does not recognise the packages included, so it seems that sourcing an external config file is useless. Likewise using `read_chunk()` instead. Therefore the question is: How to include libraries at the top, so that they are recognised in the main markdown script?
2. Say I want to define global functions externally, and then include them in the main notebook: along the same lines as above one would include them in an external `foo.R` file and include them in the main one.

Again, it seems that `read_chunk()` does not do the job, whereas `source('foo.R')` does, in this case; the documentation states that the former *"only evaluates code, but does not execute it"*: when is it *ever* the case that one wants to only evaluate the code but not execute it? Differently posed: why would one ever use `read_chunk()` rather than `source`, for practical purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > This does not recognise the packages included

   In your example, `first_package` and `second_package` **are** both available in the working environment for the second code chunk.

   Try putting `library(nycflights13)` in the R file and `head(airlines)` in the second chunk of the Rmd file. Calling `knit("main.Rmd")` would fail if the `nycflights13` package wasn't successfully loaded with `source`.
2. `read_chunk` does in fact accomplish this (along with `source`) however they go about it differently. With `source` you will have the global functions available directly after the `source` (as you have found). With `read_chunk` however, as you pointed out since it *only evaluates code, but does not execute it* you need to explicitly execute the chunk and then the function will be available. (See my example with `third_config_chunk` below. Including the empty chunk of `third_config_chunk` in the report allows the global `some_function` to be called in subsequent chunks.)

Regarding "*only evaluates code, but does not execute it*", this is an entire property of R programming known as [lazy evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html). The idea being that you may want to create a number of functions or template code which is read into your R environment but is not executed on-the-spot, allowing you to modify the environment/parameters prior to evaluation. This also allows you to execute the same code chunks multiple times whereas `source` will only run once with what is already provided.

Consider an example where you have an external R script which contains a large amount of setup code that isn't needed in your report. It is possible to format this file into many "chunks" which will be loaded into the working environment with `read_chunk` but won't be evaluated until explicitly told.

In order to externalise your `config.R` using `read_chunk()` you would write the R script as:

**config.R**

```
# ---- config_preamble
## setup code that is required for config.R
## to run but not for main.Rmd

# ---- first_config_chunk
library(nycflights13)
library(MASS)

# ---- second_config_chunk
y <- 1

# ---- third_config_chunk
some_function <- function(x) {
  x + y
}

# ---- fourth_config_chunk
some_function(10)

# ---- config_output
## code that is output during `source`
## and not wanted in main.Rmd
print(some_function(10))
```

To use this script with the externalisation methodology, you would setup **main.Rmd** as follows:

**main.Rmd**

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk('config.R')
```

```{r first_config_chunk}
```

The packages are now loaded.

```{r third_config_chunk}
```

`some_function` is now available.

```{r new_chunk}
y <- 20
```

```{r fourth_config_chunk}
```
## [1] 30

```{r new_chunk_two}
y <- 100
lapply(seq(3), some_function)
```
## [[1]]
## [1] 101
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 102
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 103

```{r source_file_instead}
source("config.R")
```
## [1] 11
````

As you can see, if you were to `source` this file, there would be no way to modify the call to `some_function` prior to execution and the call would print an output of "11". Now that the chunks are available in the environment, they can be re-called any number of times (after for example, changing the value of `y`) or used any other way in the current environment (eg. `new_chunk_two`) which would not be possible with `source` *if you didn't want the rest of the R script to execute*.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, it is more clear now. It seems, however, that my error was to call the function from within the same chunk that I used to actually "load" the chunk: apparently one needs one chunk to call the external code and only then the code can be used, but in other new chunks instead (which seems very counter-intuitive to me). To be explicit, if I did 
```{r read_first_chunk} #use loaded libraries ``` then your example wouldn't work either.

Comment: Yes, the execution chunk needs to be empty otherwise anything written in its place will be executed instead. Alternatively, you can execute the chunks into the environment immediately after `read_chunk` with `eval(parse(text=knitr:::knit_code$get("third_config_chunk")))` or whichever chunk name you like. Note however this function isn't exported by `knitr`.

Comment: I see: however, is there any difference between reading external .R files rather than .Rmd? Technically, the chunks themselves can be in the latter format (or is there any reason to prefer the former)?

Comment: Functionally, I don't believe so. It would just come down to personal preference and use-case. I use external R files if I want the chunks to comprise a larger script which can be distributed as a stand-alone source file to others unfamiliar with R markdown or called via another workflow (ie. `Rscript`). Rmd are obviously not pure R source so this wouldn't work.